# Separate data using php/mysql based on table name

Tags: php, mysql

What I am wanting to do is query my database "sc2" and search 3 tables for certain information.

I have 3 tables

```
===
Matches
====
matchid
matchname
casterid
eventid

=== 
Casters
===
casterid
casteralias
casterurl

===
Events 
===
eventid
eventname
```

The current SQL statement I am using works to a certain extent:

```
$sql = "
SELECT m.title AS matchTitle, c.casteralias matchCaster, m.dateadded matchDate, 
comp.eventname FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN 
casters AS c
ON 
c.casterid = m.casterid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
competitions AS comp
ON m.eventid = comp.id
WHERE m.title LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR 
c.casteralias LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR 
comp.eventname LIKE '%".$search."%'
ORDER BY
m.dateadded
DESC";
```

It pulls the necessary information but I am wanting to distinguish within the result set the originating table therefore I can go about manipulating the results based on what table the found results came from.

```
matchTitle  matchCaster matchDate   eventname
Hero vs Revival HuskyStarcraft  2013-06-05 15:54:05 \N
Idra vs Stephano    HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-30 13:28:05 \N
Stephano vs BabyKnight  HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-29 14:31:46 WCS Europe
Trimaster vs Destiny    HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-28 18:26:45 \N
RorO vs Innovation  HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-27 22:04:28 \N
Psy vs Camara   HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-26 02:13:10 \N
Minigun vs Maker    HuskyStarcraft  2013-05-23 20:05:00 \N
```

Results seem fine.. I just need to determine a way to differentiate the actual display of the search results based on what was searched in the first place. So if the user searches for a caster, instead of getting the recent match information, they are getting a thumbnail of the caster along with recent cast from that specific caster.

I hope I am making myself clear and thank you in advance for any advice you may have to give. :)

Comment: Can you give an example? Which columns are ambiguous in the current result set?

Comment: SQL isn't a mind-reader, so, if your intent is to retrieve other information based on the query, then in non-database code you should either augment the query to ask for the extra information you want OR get it separately.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am slowly but surely catching on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit messy, but is this what you are after

```
Select * from (
SELECT "Matches" as Source, m.title AS matchTitle, 
c.casteralias as matchCaster, m.dateadded as matchDate, comp.eventname 
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN casters AS c ON c.casterid = m.casterid
LEFT OUTER JOIN competitions AS comp ON m.eventid = comp.id
WHERE m.title LIKE '%".$search."%'
Union
SELECT "Caster", m.title, 
c.casteralias,m.dateadded, comp.eventname 
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN casters AS c ON c.casterid = m.casterid
LEFT OUTER JOIN competitions AS comp ON m.eventid = comp.id
WHERE c.casteralias LIKE '%".$search."%'
Union
SELECT "Event", m.title, 
c.casteralias,m.dateadded, comp.eventname 
FROM matches m
LEFT JOIN casters AS c ON c.casterid = m.casterid
LEFT OUTER JOIN competitions AS comp ON m.eventid = comp.id
WHERE comp.eventname LIKE '%".$search."%') allLikes

ORDER BY matchDate DESC
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm not sure if this is the way I want to go about it but I definitely appreciate the code and will study it for future reference. Thanks Tony!